# could not cast contextImp to Activity error?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

In my app, I have a custom `Activity` that all activities extend from it. I have done some common operations in that main Activity. However, I have faced an issue that I am trying to set custom action bar in the main class which extends `ActionBarActivity`. I am getting the error on title. Here is my code line that I got this error:

```
public class OSActivity extends Activity
{

public Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.context = this.getBaseContext();
    this.SetCustomActionBar(this.context);
}

private void SetCustomActionBar(final Context context)
{
    ((Activity)context).getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    ((Activity)context).getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    View acionBar = inflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar, null);
    ImageView imgAppLogo      = (ImageView)acionBar.findViewById(R.id.imgLogo);
    TextView txtTitle         = (TextView)acionBar.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    txtTitle.setText(context.getClass().getSimpleName());
    ImageButton imgMenuButton = (ImageButton)acionBar.findViewById(R.id.imgMenuButton);

    imgMenuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, v);
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actionbar_menu_titles, popup.getMenu());
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.debt_query) {
                        StartIntentFromActionBarMenuSelection(context, Activity1.class);
                        return true;
                    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.previous_payments) {
                        StartIntentFromActionBarMenuSelection(context, Activity2.class);
                        return true;
                    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.profile) {
                        StartIntentFromActionBarMenuSelection(context, Activity3.class);
                        return true;
                    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.about) {
                        StartIntentFromActionBarMenuSelection(context, Activity4.class);
                        return true;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
            popup.show();
        }
    });
    ((Activity)context).getActionBar().setCustomView(acionBar);
    ((Activity)context).getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
}

private void StartIntentFromActionBarMenuSelection(Context context, Class<?> activity)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, activity);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Also, this is the error that I've got:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ContextImpl cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
        at com.some.some.SetCustomActionBar(OSActivity.java:35)
        at com.some.some.OSActivity.onCreate(OSActivity.java:30)
```

Shortly, I handled context, but I can not get the activity from the context. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: `getContext()` is not always an Activity instance, so this works in most cases but not in all of them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is because of `getBaseContext()` is used.

On one side we have a `Context` implemetation of type `ContextImpl`, but on the other side we have also `Context`, that are implemented with `ContextWrapper`. 
`ContextWrapper` is an Adapter pattern that has base - `ContextImpl` as a field.

Activity by it's nature is `ContextWrapper` or to be more specific `ContextThemeWrapper` which adds theme to you context behaviour.

What you did there is that you took your activity's base context (the base of the ContextWrapper) and expect, you will be able to cast it to activity again.
In many cases, there are no reason to use baseContext, or applicationContext, especially in activity, where you need that context to be `Themed` to be use with View hierarchy updates.

So instead of

```
this.context = this.getBaseContext();
this.SetCustomActionBar(this.context);
```

you should use:

```
this.SetCustomActionBar(this);
```